# Is there any historical basis to the four Toltec agreements?

Tags: history, culture

Mexican author Miguel Ruiz published a best-selling self-help book called [The Four Agreements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Four_Agreements), claiming to be based on ancient Toltec wisdom. The four agreements are as follows:

1. Be Impeccable With Your Word
2. Don't Take Anything Personally
3. Don't Make Assumptions
4. Always Do Your Best

Is there any historical evidence of these agreements coming from Toltec society?

Comment: I haven't read the book but it appears that the claim is that this comes from oral tradition, not any written source. I don't know who the alleged sources of this oral tradition are from the author but it's likely impossible to prove their Toltec origin, and also impossible to disprove unless someone admitted to lying somewhere.

Comment: Oral tradition from many centuries ago must almost certainly have been recorded, even if very indirectly. Surely this can't be the first person capable of writing that has heard of the four agreements.

Comment: It seems there is a difference between the archaeological term "Toltec", for a particular civilisation, and [its wider use in local mythology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toltec#Toltecs_as_myth). In [this interview with the author](https://www.oprah.com/spirit/ellen-degeneress-o-magazine-interview-with-author-don-miguel-ruiz/all) he says 'In this story, Toltec means "artist."' suggesting that by "Toltec wisdom" he means a local wisdom attributed broadly as "Toltec", not necessarily a millennium of unbroken transmission.